# xrdp caused issues, trying to undo damage

Tags: xrdp, smb, cockpit

I've been happily working away on my installation of 20.04 and Cockpit, providing a solid ZFS volume via SMB to my Mac. As it's a headless server I wanted to gain remote access so installed xrdp. It's worked great...however

I rebooted the Ubuntu server and I couldn't connect via Cockpit, SMB or xrdp. I connected via ssh and looked around but couldn't find any issues. As the only thing I had changed was installing xrdp, so I uninstalled it and hey presto...I could connect via Cockpit again.

Unfortunately I still can't get the Mac to connect via SMB.

smbclient shows:

/etc/samba$ smbclient -L localhost

Enter WORKGROUP\scott's password:

```
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    TimeMachineBackup Disk      
    Share          Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (UbuntuNAS server (Samba, Ubuntu))
    BigladZFS_FileServer Disk      Comment: /BigladZFS/FileServer 
    SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

So it appears to be up. I also have a Windows 10 laptop around and it also can't see the servers shares.

ufw is disabled...

Strangely, attempting to connect from the CLI on the mac shows:

SCOTTS-MAC-PRO ~ % mount -t smbfs smb://XXX:YYY@192.168.0.85/Share ./SMBTEST

mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Operation timed out

It doesn't care about the username or the password...or even the /Share name...just returns the timed out error (in no time at all). Change the ip address and it appears to go and try and find it, then fails.

Where should I start looking?

Comment: This sounds like a caching issue on your Mac. You may be able to resolve it with: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`, which will restart the DNS service.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I would have thought using the explicit IP address would have negated any DNS issues, also the Win10 laptop can't see any SMB shares (or even the presence of the server on the network). I tried what you suggested but it made no difference. It doesn't seem to matter what I tried from the CLI (smbutil  etc) just returns server connection failed: Operation timed out. However this is an instant error, it's not like it trying for a while and timing out.

Comment: Also...I've just stopped the smbd service on the server and I get the same error on the Mac and Win10 laptop. So the only thing that can see the smb shares...the server itself. Not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that by installing xrdp, the firewalld was started. I had only been looking at ufw. I stopped firewalld and then disabled it..all my shares are working again.

I think I'll re-install xrdp again and check the firewalld again.

Comment: Nope...not sure what happened, I've just re-installed xrdp and it doesn't appear to have started the firewalld.